# How to run a script but print only the output obtained after 1 min for first time and 3 min after every time till the script runs?(Python)

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, yolo

So I have am working with YOLOv4 to process video frames for object detection of one class : Human and every time a Human is detected in frame it prints a line in the terminal " Number of human detected :" and gives the number of human detected in a particular frame. Now I want the code to run as it is but instead of printing the above output for every frame, it should print the output of the videoframe it processes at the first 1 min mark and there after at every 3 min mark till the video is fully processed. So for a 5 min video, i would want the statement to be printed at the following videotimestamps: 1:00, 4:00. For a 8 min video it would be: 1:00, 4:00, 7:00.... and so on. I tried using schedule module but it seems to just schedule the entire code to run after 1 min.

```
    from imutils.video import VideoStream

    from imutils.video import FPS

    import numpy as np

    import argparse

    import imutils

    import time

    import cv2

    from collections import OrderedDict

    import numpy as np

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    import datetime

    import schedule
    import time
    from time import sleep 

    file = "test2"

    input = "C:/Users/asmita.nandi/Downloads/" + file + ".mp4"

    output = "C:/Users/asmita.nandi/Downloads/" + file + ".avi"

    net = cv2.dnn.readNet( "C:/Users/asmita.nandi/Downloads/custom-yolov4-tiny_human-608 
   (1).cfg","C:/Users/asmita.nandi/Downloads/custom-yolov4-tiny-detector_human.weights")



    labelsPath = "C:/Users/asmita.nandi/Downloads/human_label.txt"

    def event(input,output,net,labelsPath):

        LABELS = open(labelsPath).read().strip().split("\n")

        np.random.seed(1)


        cmap = plt.get_cmap('tab20b')

        colors = [cmap(i)[:3] for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 6)]

        CONF_THRESH, NMS_THRESH = 0.25, 0.25



        vs = cv2.VideoCapture(input)

        fp = vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

 

        writer = None

 

        W = None

        H = None

 

 

        totalFrames = 0



        TotalHuman = 0

        while True:

            frame = vs.read()

            frame = frame[1] if input else frame

            if input is not None and frame is None:

               break

            (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]
            print(H,W)

                

            if W is None or H is None:

               (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]

 

            if output is not None and writer is None:

                fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")

                writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc,fp,(W,H), True)

 

               

                               

                               

            ln = net.getLayerNames()

            ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

            blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255.0, (608,608), swapRB=True, crop=False)

                
    
            net.setInput(blob)

            start = time.time()

            layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)

            print(layerOutputs)

            end = time.time()

 

            boxes = []

            confidences = []

            classIDs = []

            (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]

                
                # loop over each of the layer outputs

            for output in layerOutputs:

 

            # loop over each of the detections

                for detection in output:

 
            

                    scores = detection[5:]

                                                #print(detection)

                    classID = np.argmax(scores)

      

                    confidence = scores[classID]

      

                    if confidence > CONF_THRESH:

 

                                                                #print("Box")

                        box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W, H, W, H])

                        (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")


                        x = int(centerX - (width / 2))

                        y = int(centerY - (height / 2))


                        boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])

                        confidences.append(float(confidence))                                                                   

                        classIDs.append(classID)      

        idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, CONF_THRESH,NMS_THRESH)     

        ObjectCount = {} 

        if len(idxs) > 0:     

            for i in idxs.flatten():      

                (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])

                (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3]) 
 

                color = colors[classIDs[i]]

                color = [i * 255 for i in color]

                class_name = LABELS[classIDs[i]]

                cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),color,2)

                # if class_name == "Human":

                cv2.putText(frame, class_name,(x, y-10),0, 0.5,color,2)

               

                                                

                obj, conf = LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i]
            
            if obj not in ObjectCount.keys():

                ObjectCount[obj] = 1

            else:

                ObjectCount[obj] += 1
                
            allvalues=[]
            allvalues.append(ObjectCount[obj])
            print("Number of Humans detected ", max(allvalues))


                                               

 

 

    if writer is not None:

        writer.write(frame)

 

                # show the output frame

                #cv2_imshow(frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

 

                # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop

    if key == ord("q"):

        break

 

                # increment the total number of frames processed thus far and

                # then update the FPS counter

    totalFrames += 1

    fps.update()

 

# stop the timer and display FPS information

#for (objectID, centroid) in objects.items():

                #print(objectID, centroids)

 

fps.stop()

print("[INFO] elapsed time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))

print(totalFrames)

#print(info)

# check to see if we need to release the video writer pointer

if writer is not None:

    writer.release()

 

# if we are not using a video file, stop the camera video stream

if not input:

    vs.stop()

 

# otherwise, release the video file pointer

else:

    vs.release()

 

# close any open windows

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(event(input,output,net,labelsPath))
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If you know your frames per second, you could calculate the time passed and only print if the number of frames that passed is divisible by the number you want. hope this makes sense

Comment: fps will vary from video to video so that doesn't seem feasible option

Comment: There should be a way to get the FPS of a video file using OpenCV